# Angular Typescript check type of Class

Tags: angular, typescript

`file.service.ts`:

```
downloadRaw(id: string, revision: number = 0): Observable<HttpResponse<Blob> | JsonError> {
    let params = new HttpParams();
    params = params.set('revision', revision.toString());

    return this.http
      .get(this.downloadRawFileUrl
        .replace(':id', id),
        {
          observe: 'response',
          responseType: 'blob',
          params: params 
        })
      .pipe(
        catchError(error => this.errorService.handleError(error))
      );
}
```

`error.service.ts`:

```
handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse): Observable<JsonError> {
    let jsonError: JsonError = new JsonError();
    if(error.error instanceof Blob) {
        let promise = error.error.text().then((text: string) => {
            let jsonError = JSON.parse(text);
            return jsonError;
        });
        return from(promise);
    } else {
        jsonError = error.error;
        return of(jsonError);
    }
}
```

Here is my component:

```
 this.fileService.downloadRaw(fileGUID).subscribe(
      (response: (HttpResponse<Blob> | JsonError)) => {
        if (response instanceof JsonError) {
            ...
        } else {
            ...
        }
      }
    );
```

but it goes to `else` code block in any case, what's wrong? How can I fix that?

Comment: Do you actually instantiate `JsonError` anywhere? Most likely you have a vanilla object.

Comment: @jonrsharpe updated question a bit

Comment: `let jsonError: JsonError = new JsonError();` is completely unused, because any context in which you return `jsonError` or an observable of it, you've overwritten that value.

Comment: "but it goes to else code block in any case" because an exception didn't occur? the `else` statement is if everything went ok

Comment: As mentioned by @jonrsharpe the error is in `handleError` it's not returning a JsonError, it's returning either the result from parse or `error.error` which both are probably of type `any` and that's why it allows you to assign it.

Comment: Okay, the reason is known, how to get that code working?